# Can find the SVN branch for the current release of nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

The download is 2.1.2GA, but I can only see 2.1.x in a subversion branch.

https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/branches/2.1.x/nhibernate

any ideas where I can download what they are releasing?

Answer (score 0):

Not SVN but it seems to be here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate-2.1.2.GA-src.zip/download